# Search bar, html css. (Atom User)

Tags: html, css

I started coding a week ago and I have few issues with my css and my html. I cannot get the search bar to be smaller and to adjust to the top next to my logo.I changed the  font size of "search", but it seems that it does not appear anymore. I think that my search bar is maybe too low. Here are my sheets, please if someone can help.
I really do not know, maybe I have forgot few line of codes.

```css
/*essentials css */
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.43;
  color: #484848;
}

p{

font-size: 16px
margin: 0;
padding: 0;

  }
  a:link {
    font-size: : 16px;
    text-decoration: none;


  }
  a:visited{
    text-decoration: none;

  }

  h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ul, ol, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  ul, ol{

    list-style-type;

  }

  ::selection {

color: #fff;
background-color: #333;

}

 ::-moz-selection {

  color: #fff;
  background-color: : #333;

}
/* top- nap */

.top-nav {
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;

}

.logo:link {

  color: #484848;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: : all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  border-right:1px solid #ccc;



}

.logo:visited{

   color: #484848;
}

.logo:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.logo img {
  position: relative;
padding: 12px 18px;
width: 100px;
border-right: : 1px solid #ccc;
vertical-align: : middle;

}

/* nav-search css */
#nav-search-wrapper {
display: inline-block;
width: 490px;
height: 100%;

}

#nav-search-wrapper form input {
  padding: 22px 10px 18px 52px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: :red;

}
#nav-search-wrapper form input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: orange;
  font-size:17px;
}
#nav-search-wrapper form input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: orange;
}
#nav-search-wrapper form input:-ms-input-placeholder {
}
#nav-search-wrapper form input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
        <title>ElephantRoom</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name"viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
      </head>
<body>
  <!-- Top-NAV HTML-->
  <div class="top-nav">
    <a href="index.html" class="logo">
      <img src="logo.png" alt="ElephantRoom" />
    </a>
    <div id="nav-search-wrapper">
      <form method="GET" action="index.html">
        <input type="text"name="search" id="nav-search" placeholder="Search"/>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to move your search bar / text closer to the left of your logo?

You should adjust the padding within the search bar, currently it's being pushed 52px from the left:

```
#nav-search-wrapper form input {
  padding: 22px 10px 18px 52px; // change padding
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: red;
}
```

to something like:

```
#nav-search-wrapper form input {
  padding: 18px 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: No problem, please mark as the answer if this solved your issue so it can help others in the future.